# Create table Agent and insert values to sqlite table in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

I am new in android app developement. I tried to insert values to SQLite database through the code below ; and it is not working. I'm desperate! 
Can anyone pleaaaaase help me???

this is DatabaseHelper.JAVA

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "agents.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "agents";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_MATRICULE = "matricule";
    private static final String COLUMN_NOM = "nom";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRENOM = "prenom";
    private static final String COLUMN_FONCTION = "fonction";
    private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String COLUMN_PASS = "pass";
    private static final String COLUMN_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String COLUMN_CIN = "cin";

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table agents (id integer primary key not null , " +
            ", matricule integer not null , nom text not null , prenom text not null , fonction text not null , email text not null , pass text not null , address text not null);";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        this.db = db;
    }

    public void insertAgent(Agent a) {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        String query = "select * from agents";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query , null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();

        values.put(COLUMN_ID , count);
        values.put(COLUMN_MATRICULE, a.getMatricule());
        values.put(COLUMN_NOM, a.getNom());
        values.put(COLUMN_PRENOM, a.getPrenom());
        values.put(COLUMN_FONCTION, a.getFonction());
        values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, a.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_PASS, a.getPass());
        values.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS, a.getAddress());
        values.put(COLUMN_CIN, a.getCin());

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public String searchPass(String matricule)
    {
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "select matricule, pass from "+TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query , null);
        String a, b;
        b = "not found";
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                a = cursor.getString(0);

                if(a.equals(matricule))
                {
                    b = cursor.getString(1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return b;
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(query);
        this.onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Agent.JAVA

```
public class Agent {
    String matricule,nom,prenom,fonction,email,pass,address,cin;


    public String getMatricule() {
        return matricule;
    }

    public void setMatricule(String matricule) {
        this.matricule = matricule;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public String getFonction() {
        return fonction;
    }

    public void setFonction(String fonction) {
        this.fonction = fonction;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCin() {
        return cin;
    }

    public void setCin(String cin) {
        this.cin = cin;
    }
    }
```

InscRire.JAVA

```
public class InscRire extends Activity {

    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sinscrire);
    }

    public void onSignUpClick(View v)
    {
        if(v.getId()== R.id.Bsinscrire)
        {
            EditText matricule = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFmatricule);
            EditText nom = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFnom);
            EditText prenom = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFprenom);
            EditText fonction = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFfonction);
            EditText email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFemail);
            EditText pass1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFpass1);
            EditText pass2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFpass2);
            EditText address = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFaddress);
            EditText cin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFcin);

            String matriculestr = matricule.getText().toString();
            String nomstr = nom.getText().toString();
            String prenomstr = prenom.getText().toString();
            String fonctionstr = fonction.getText().toString();
            String emailstr = email.getText().toString();
            String pass1str = pass1.getText().toString();
            String pass2str = pass2.getText().toString();
            String addressstr = address.getText().toString();
            String cinstr = cin.getText().toString();

            if(!pass1str.equals(pass2str))
            {
                //popup msg
                Toast pass = Toast.makeText(InscRire.this , "Mot de passe incorrect!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                pass.show();
            }
            else
            {
                //insert the detailes in database
                Agent a = new Agent();
                a.setMatricule(matriculestr);
                a.setNom(nomstr);
                a.setPrenom(prenomstr);
                a.setFonction(fonctionstr);
                a.setEmail(emailstr);
                a.setPass(pass1str);
                a.setAddress(addressstr);
                a.setCin(cinstr);

                helper.insertAgent(a);
            }

        }

    }


}
```

Main.JAVA

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v)
    {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.Bconnexion)
        {
            EditText a = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFmatricule);
            String mat = a.getText().toString();
            EditText b = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFpass);
            String pass = b.getText().toString();

            String mot_de_pass = helper.searchPass(mat);
            if(pass.equals(mot_de_pass))
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Display.class);
                i.putExtra("Matricule",mat);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast temp = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , "Matricule et mot de passe incorrect!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                temp.show();
            }



        }
        if(v.getId() == R.id.Binscrire)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InscRire.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Display.JAVA

```
public class Display extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display);
        String matricule = getIntent().getStringExtra("Matricule");

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVmatricule);
        tv.setText(matricule);

    }
}
```

sinscrire.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Matricule "
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/TFmatricule"
        android:inputType="number"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Nom"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/TFnom" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Prenom"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/TFprenom" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Fonction"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/TFfonction" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Email"
        android:id="@+id/textView5" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/TFemail" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Mot de passe"
        android:id="@+id/textView6" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/TFpass1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Confirmer mot de passe"
        android:id="@+id/textView7" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/TFpass2" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Address"
        android:id="@+id/textView8" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/TFaddress" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Cin"
        android:id="@+id/textView9" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/TFcin" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sinscrire"
        android:id="@+id/Bsinscrire"
        android:onClick="onSignUpClick" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Main.XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Connexion"
        android:id="@+id/Bconnexion"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Matricule"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TFmatricule"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Mot de passe"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TFmatricule"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/TFpass"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="S'inscrire ici"
        android:id="@+id/Binscrire"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Bconnexion"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Display.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Welcome,"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/emptyString"
        android:id="@+id/TVmatricule" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What bug do you have ? What is not working ?

Comment: @lord-of-dark when i click on the Button "Sinscrire" i get this error:
' at com.example.priya.activitydemo.DatabaseHelper.insertAgent(DatabaseHelper.java:57)'
                                                                                    at com.example.priya.activitydemo.InscRire.onSignUpClick(InscRire.java:62)

Comment: Could you post the rest of that error ? That is not the complete stack trace,